# Wine explorer on specific prefix?

Tags: command-line, wine

I’m trying to open the explorer.exe from wine through the terminal. When I try to open explorer.exe via a gui It crashes but I can open from the terminal. Now the issue is that I have two wineprefixes installed one is a 32 and one is 64 bit. If I do `wine explorer /e` in terminal it opens the wrong prefix, the prefix I wish to open is called steam. How do I do this via the terminal?

Extra info: Running `wine explorer /e` opens "home/.wine/"
The steam prefix is located in "home/.local/share/wineprefixes/steam/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I've never found any documentation discussing this my personal experiences have shown that Wine assigns different letters to each prefix, which I guess makes sense because when you install multiple versions of Windows for real there are certain circumstances that can result in each installation having a different letter drive rather than all using `C:\` (Eg: the use of logical partitions.) but it's still really weird.

Short hand commands for Wine only seem to work for default prefix because the command assumes the use of `C:\` . When you install wine it creates a prefix and assigns it as `C:\` any additional prefixes you make may have different letter drives. You will need to find out which letter drive your 2nd prefix is using. Most likely `D:\` .

One way to be sure would be to copy `cmd.exe` from Windows (Not the Wine `cmd.exe` it doesn't work) to the prefix and launch it. It's located at `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and it will read something like `D:\Users\Username`.

Example Wine Command For Launching 7-zip:

```
wine start 'C:\Program Files\7-zip\7zFM.exe'
```

Keep in mind that **if** the software installed within the Wine prefix is configured for a `C:\` setup but is running from a `D:\` configured prefix, then it won't run unless it's a simple program that doesn't need to look for other files or that uses `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` or a variant when searching rather than `D:\` . Wine really needs to provide a more in depth explanation of the multi-prefix feature, because clearly some odd stuff goes on.